# How to convert a String to String array ( This string contains a minus number )

Tags: java, arrays

There is a

```
String temp = "M0-1"
```

How to convert this String to a String[] ?

If you output the new String array, the result should be:

```
String[] newStringArray;
newStringArray[0] = M;
newStringArray[1] = 0;
newStringArray[2] = -1;
```

The last element of the new String array should be "-1", which means "-1" will be considered as a entirety, but not "-" and "1" separately.

I tried to use String.split("") parse this string, but only got a String array like this:

```
String[] newStringArray;
newStringArray[0] = M;
newStringArray[1] = 0;
newStringArray[2] = -;
newStringArray[3] = 1;
```

UPDATE: String 56 should be [5, 6], and -10 should be [-1, 0]

Comment: What do you want it to do? What should the output be?

Comment: @Jon Sorry about my mistake, I just updated my question.

Comment: More sample inputs would be useful, e.g. should 56 be [5,6] or [56], and what about -10 ([-1,0] or [-10])?

Comment: Under what criteria are these strings split?

Comment: @NullUserException I tried to use "" null character but it was not working well

Comment: @increment1 56 should be [5,6], and -10 should be [-1, 0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `split()` will do it:

```
String[] array = temp.split("(?<=[^-])");
```

It works by splitting when the previous character is *not* a `-`

That odd-looking regex is called a *look-behind*. Its syntax is `(?<=regex)`, which is a non-capturing assertion that the preceding input matches the specified regex, which in this case is `[^-]`, which means "any character that isn't a minus".

There are 4 versions of this kind of assertion:

- `(?=regex)` is a *positive look ahead*, meaning the next input must match `regex`
- `(?!regex)` is a *negative look ahead*, meaning the next input must not match `regex`
- `(?<=regex)` is a *positive look behind*, meaning the preceeding input must match `regex`
- `(?<!regex)` is a *negative look behind*, meaning the nepreceedingxt input must not match `regex`

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "M0-1";
    String[] newStringArray = temp.split("(?<=[^-])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newStringArray));
}
```

Output:

```
[M, 0, -1]
```

Comment: Awesome, elegant solution. Nice explanation, and test code. Well done!

Comment: Could you explain what's the "(?<=[^-])" means? Is that the regular expression？

Comment: @MilesZhang OK - See answer for explanation of funky regex

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I saw your edit.

If you really want an array, then you'll have to determine the size beforehand:

```
int finalSize = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    Character curr = new Character(temp.charAt(i));
    if(curr.isLetter() || curr.isDigit()) {
        finalSize++;
    }
}
```

Then you can put things in the array:

```
String[] tempArray = new String[finalSize];
int index = 0;
String splicer = "";
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    Character curr = new Character(temp.charAt(i));
    splicer += curr; // Adds the current character to the current String.
    if(curr.isLetter() || curr.isDigit()) { // If it's a digit or a letter,
        temp[index] = splicer;              // then you'll store the current String
        splicer = "";                       // Reset the current String.
        index++;                            // And move on to the next index.
    }
}
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I took some serious leaps of faith into the type of logic you were actually desiring as you only gave us one single String to build logic from, not a standard format you desired, if this does not fit your format, please give us more example strings which you want to convert to String[] and you can tweak the logic to make it fit your string format.

```
  String string = "M0-1";
  char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
  List<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();   
  for(int x = 0; x < charArray.length; x++){
       String currentString = Character.toString(charArray[x]);
       if(currentString.contains("-")){
             stringArrayList.add(currentString + Character.toString(charArray[x + 1]));
             x++;
             continue;
       }
       stringArrayList.add(currentString);
  } 

  String[] stringArray = new String[stringArrayList.size()]; 
  stringArrayList.toArray(stringArray);
  System.out.println(stringArray);
```

This logic will separate all characters unless they are preceded by a "-" and if so it will include 1 character following the "-".  As I said above, I took some large leaps of faith from the information you provided, update the question with more details and I'm certain we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regular expression to do this. Use regular expression to get the tail number of String, and use substring method to spit the String two part, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String temp = "M0-1";
    String regexp = "\\-?\\d+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
    matcher.find();
    String[] result = {temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf(matcher.group())),
            temp.substring(temp.indexOf(matcher.group()),temp.length())};
    System.out.println(result[0]);
    System.out.println(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this.

```
String sample = "M0-1e-2f-gh-";
char[] chars = sample.toCharArray();
List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  // second test case is to avoid index out of bounds exception during append
  if (chars[i] == '-' && (i+1) < chars.length) {
    newArray.add("-" + chars[i+1]); // append the next element
    i++; // skip the next element because it's already been appended
  } else {
    newArray.add("" + chars[i]);
  }
}

// toArray() returns an array of type Object[] so pass a new String[] object,
// put the ArrayList elements there, then return as String[]
String[] results = newArray.toArray(new String[newArray.size()]);
```

`results[]` should contain ["M", "0", "-1", "e", "-2", "f", "-g", "h", "-"].